# Magento 2 : Expected HIT on the second page load after product price update

Tags: magento2, error, marketplace, package

I have submitted an extension to **Magento Marketplace** but they reported below error:

> Expected HIT on the second page load. Expected HIT on the second page
>   load after product price update.
>
> {"command":"Varnish PageCache Test","output":{"Expected HIT on the
>   second page load.":["http://magento.local/simple-product-1.html
>   page doesn't contain HIT in cache
>   header.","http://magento.local/simple-product-2.html page doesn't
>   contain HIT in cache
>   header.","http://magento.local/simple-product-3.html page doesn't
>   contain HIT in cache header.","http://magento.local/category-1.html
>   page doesn't contain HIT in cache
>   header.","http://magento.local/category-2.html page doesn't contain
>   HIT in cache header.","http://magento.local/ page doesn't contain
>   HIT in cache header."],"Expected HIT on the second page load after
>   product price update.":["http://magento.local/simple-product-1.html
>   page doesn't contain HIT in cache
>   header.","http://magento.local/simple-product-3.html page doesn't
>   contain HIT in cache header."]}

I am not sure what exactly to add to get the package be successfully **validated at Magento Marketplace**. Please help me if someone have any idea on it.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 3):

This error means that the extension prevents product and category pages from being cached by Varnish. One possible cause is using `cacheable="false"` in one or more blocks on product and category pages.

### Background

In late 2017 Magento [announced](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Varnish-Cache-Validation-beginning-1-2-18/ba-p/81203) that they will require all extensions submitted to the Marketplace to be compatible with full-page cache (Varnish):

> Keeping in line with our efforts to improve the quality of all extensions on Marketplace, as of 1/2/18 we will be implementing Varnish cache validation during Technical Review for all M2 submissions.The Varnish test verifies products do not break Varnish caching when in production mode.

### Full-page caching in Magento 2

Magento 2 distinguishes two types of cacheable content: [public and private](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Varnish-Cache-Validation-beginning-1-2-18/ba-p/81203) - the former being everything that's publicly accessible to anyone (e.g. category listing), the later everything that's specific to a single user (e.g. shopping cart).

The way those two types of content are handled is that a full-page cache (Varnish) caches the whole page with only *public* content present, and any *private* content on this page is handled by [UI Components](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html) in the browser.

### Testing an extension with Varnish

To test whether an extension is compatible with Varnish:

1. Configure the environment to use Varnish as described in [Magento dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html)
2. Test the product page: `curl -I http://magento2.local/sample-producth.html`. In the response headers there should be `X-Magento-Cache-Debug` with value `MISS`. Run the command again - now the header should have value `HIT`.
3. Repeat the same test for the category page.

If you don't get a `HIT` on second and following attempts, make sure that your environment is configured correctly by running the test on a vanilla Magento instance.

If you don't see the `X-Magento-Cache-Debug` header at all, make sure that Magento is running in `developer` mode and your request goes through Varnish and not directly to Apache/nginx.

Comment: @Maniek, I configured the varnish 6 in my local, and when I ran the curl -I <product_url>, I didn't see any values like X-Magento-Cach-Debug in the result, then right now my application in developer mode.